# Do i need to declare variable inside function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I haven't declared a variable (a) like this `Let a`
but still it is working when i am calling my function. I wanted to know why is this working?

```js
const mainHeading = document.querySelector("h1");

function positiveOrNegative(a) {
  if (a > 0) {
    mainHeading.textContent = " 'a' is a positive number";
  } else if (a < 0) {
    mainHeading.textContent = " 'a' is a negative number";
  } else {
    mainHeading.textContent = " 'a' is neither +ve nor -ve";
  }
}
positiveOrNegative(-5);
```

Comment: It's "declared" in the function definition `function positiveOrNegative(*a*) {`

Comment: I believe you should use `let` instead of `const` for `mainHeading`. See [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) documentation.

Comment: @Peter Krebs, `mainHeading` doesn't change, at least in this snippet, so no need to use `let`. It's constant.

Comment: @PeterKrebs There's no assignment to the `mainHeading` variable, using `const` is fine

Comment: Okay I assumed you should only use `const` if you want to say "don't change properties of this, please". But as we know know OP was asking something different.